# Looking for help identifying projections and reprojecting

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system

I'm still struggling with projections in QGIS. The "Vogelschutzgebiete" reprojection worked. But these ones seem to be tougher:

[www.projektidee.org/images/extern/Gemeinden.zip](http://%20www.projektidee.org/images/extern/Aember.zip)

as well as the same URL with **Aemter.zip** at the end.

Are these the same projections? Does anyone here by any chance know how to reproject these to EPSG:32633 (WGS84 UTM33N)? (shapes without projection information are a pain in the a...)

Referring also to this thread: http://forum.qgis.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=10244&sid=52667e4eb2cfdad92b4f88e160c1b577

Comment: Hi, we meet again! I think that Aemter.shp might be either in EPSG:31468 or EPSG:31464, but I'm not sure (there appears to be a small shift). It might be worth reprojecting the shapefile from EPSG:31468 to EPSG:32633 to see how it fits with your other data.

Comment: I think that the Gemeinden and the Amter shapefiles are both projected to EPSG:31468 (DHDN/3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 4) or something near to this. What worries me is that they don't map onto the real world very well, there appears to be a shift to the north of about 1500 metres, which is why I haven't presented this as an answer. Nick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should your shapefiles look like these ones??

[image: Gemeinden]

[image: Aemter]

I simply create two new files Aemter.prj and Gemeinden.prj, which contain both the following text:

GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]
(actually, I did not create them, just made copies of an existing one and renamed them properly)

Hope this helps, let me know, if this answer is useful to you

Kurt
edit:
your new file looks like this to me: 
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the reply. In the meantime I have found the solution I had to convert from EPSG:2398

Comment: Hi! 

I still have a problems with other data of this type.

Coult somewone of you have a look at this shape and see if it works for you to reproject it to UTM33N / WGS84?

best regards and thanks
desputin

http://projektidee.org/images/extern/ffh.zip